# ReactJS - Opening index.html returns black page but npm start works as expected. How to deploy?

Tags: html, reactjs, express

I got done building a webapp and want to put it online.

So I wrote a simple express app to return index.html when someone makes a get request.

But when response is carried out, it only displays a blank page

serve -s build works perfectly. But returning index.html through express doesnt (blank page)

So, how can I get index.html to render the JS?

**OR should I somehow be running 'serve -s build' when someone makes a get request?**

I have tried placing `<script src="../src/index.js" type="module"></script>` under head but that didnt work either.

How do I successfully deploy this app?

Comment: You should build your React app once and point Express to your build folder.

Comment: meaning I should return index.html from there? I have tried doing that but that doesnt work either. Unless I should be pointing to some other file/folder.

Comment: Did you point to your static resources too? For example `app.use(express.static("./build"));`.

Comment: that worked!! thank you so much!


But what exactly did that do? Point to the rest of the build files?


Also, I still have a couple of MIME type errors (files not loaded), should I be concerned about them? Or can this error occur because of caching or something?

Comment: Well, you have to point to your CSS and JS files so that they can be requested, too. `express.static` does that automatically. What MIME type errors are you getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as DallogFheir said, had to point to the static resources.